# Why is the Fourier transform of a non-Abelian finite group the weighted superposition over all irreps?

Tags: finite-groups, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, symmetric-groups

I am going through the lecture note of Andrew Childs on [Nonabelian Fourier analysis](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~amchilds/teaching/w13/l06.pdf). I would like to quote from the note:

[image]

**My question:**

Why does it have to be *weighted superposition* and not *equal superposition* of the irreps?

Comment: Would like to look at this but the physics code words slow me down too much.

Comment: I would think it is probably obvious from the text that follows the definition which properties hinge upon the thing being defined that way. Why do you think equal superposition is a good idea??

Comment: @rschwieb, I am not claiming equal superposition might be a good idea. I would like to know why weighted superposition is chosen over equal one.

Comment: but why would you ask such a thing unless you thought an equal superposition was a reasonable idea? If you're just asking why it isn't your favorite random thing X, the line of inquiry is not very purposeful.

Comment: As I said,  I would like to know the rationale behind taking weighted average.

Comment: ah, now phrasing it that way is certainly more focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to virtually any question of the form "why is this construction defined this way" is "because doing that gives it nice properties."

I can guess, for example, that this is needed in equation 10 to make the transformation unitary.

Later on between equations 16 and 17 it mentions another property about the way it decomposes the regular representations, and quite probably different choices of the definition you're asking about would not have the same property.

I would encourage you to take whatever alternative definition you have in mind and test it to see if it has either of these features.