# How does the weighted superposition of irreps make the Fourier transform of a finite group unitary?

Tags: finite-groups, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, symmetric-groups

This is supplementary to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591111/why-is-the-fourier-transform-of-a-non-abelian-finite-group-the-weighted-superpos). In the lecture note of Andrew Childs on [Nonabelian Fourier analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591111/why-is-the-fourier-transform-of-a-non-abelian-finite-group-the-weighted-superpos), it is said that the Fourier transform of a finite group is the weighted superposition of the irreps.

[image]

When I asked what the rationale behind taking the weighted superposition is, it was answered that weighted superposition is taken to make the transform unitary.

**My question:**
How does weighted superposition make the transform unitary?

Comment: Have you tried expanding $\langle \hat x | \hat x \rangle$?

Comment: I did it for $S_5$.

Comment: Can you simplify it to $1$?

Comment: Did you mean  $S_1$?

Comment: No!  I mean: for any kets, we should have $\langle a | b \rangle \in \Bbb C$.  What makes this transformation unitary, I believe, is that 
$$
\langle \hat x | \hat y \rangle = \delta_{xy}
$$
just as
$$
\langle x|y\rangle = \delta_{xy}
$$
for $x,y \in G$.